# Writing (what I believe to be) a Left Anti Join in SOQL

Tags: soql

So the end result I'm hoping to achieve is to do a Left Anti-Join in SOQL without using Roll-Up Summary fields or Apex. Here's the scenario:

We have 2 custom objects, say `Property__c` and `Connected_Device__c`.

`Connected_Device__c` has the 2 following fields:

- A lookup field to `Property__c`
- a picklist field named `Type__c` with the picklist values: `'Hub', 'Thermostat', 'Garage'`

meaning our property records will have a related list of connected devices. Here's the scenario:

- **Property A** has 3 connected devices, one for each of the different `Type__c` values.
- **Property B** has 2 connected devices, one for `Thermostat` and one for `Garage`.

If I wanted to query the properties that had **at least 1** connected **Hub** devices, I could use the query:

```
SELECT Property__c, COUNT(Id) hubs
FROM Connected_Device__c
WHERE Type__c = 'Hub' 
GROUP BY Property__c
HAVING COUNT(Id) >= 1
```

But what if I wanted to find all the properties that have **0 connected Hub devices** but that still have **other linked connected devices** (i.e. **Property B**)?

I wouldn't be able to build a query on the `Connected_Device__c` records that have `Type__c = 'Hub'`, since the query result would always be empty.

And using a `NOT()` statement (i.e. `(NOT Type__c = 'Hub')`) would result in **both** property records being returned, since both have `Thermostat` and `Garage` connected devices.

---

I know that ultimately I could build a simpler SOQL query and then use logic in Apex to to get the result I want, or have Roll-Up Summaries on the object that count the number of **Hub** and **non-Hub** connected devices, but this is more of an exercise in determining if this is possible with SOQL alone.

Let me know if I need to add more to the question/clarify anything!

Comment: The "community" tag refers to a specific Salesforce feature (Salesforce communities, now called "experience cloud", for portals/sites a company would allow its non-Salesforce user customers to use), so I've removed that tag.

Comment: Haha for some reason I interpreted it as a "question for the community". Thanks for the edit @Derek F!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd be something like:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Property__c
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Property__c FROM Connected_Device___c WHERE Type__c = 'Hub')
  AND Id IN (SELECT Property__c FROM Connected_Device__c)
```

Note that you must use `AND`, as `OR` isn't supported. The `Id IN` and `Id NOT IN` syntaxes are incredibly useful for finding parent records that meet certain child criteria.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @sfdcfox. I appreciate the help on this!